# How do I end a loop with pynput in my raspberry pi?

Tags: python, loops

```
import pynput
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
seguir = True

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
#GPIO.cleanup()



print("y. Comenzar corrimiento de bits: \nq. Detener corrimiento de bits")
letra = input()

while seguir:  
    GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)
    print("Led = OFF")
    GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
    print("Led = OFF")
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)
    print("Led = OFF")
    GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
    print("Led = ON")
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
    print("Led = ON")
    GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
    print("Led = OFF")
    time.sleep(1)
```

I really don't know how listener actually works or how to use it. I have read the documentation but don't seem to actually understand it. I just want to end the while loop when the key 'q' is pressed

Comment: As a simple suggestion, terminate the program using Control-C, which works in most shells. No need to build anything special into your program. Intercepting single keys from inside of a program is much more complicated than you'd expect, so I'd rather avoid it.

Comment: Thank you! I've read about using ctrl-c however, I need to use the 'q' for my program as it is a requirement for my assignment. I do appreciate the advice though!